# Search by traversing Multiple Tables in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, search, activerecord, rails-activerecord, advanced-search

In Employees Index page I have column 'Region Name', with a search field.

Now i need to search column-'Region Name' from 'Employee' table, traversing to 'Region' table

```
Employee -> Company -> Organization -> Region
```

Employee table has foreign key of Company(company_id)

Company table has foreign key of Organization(organization_id)

Organization table has foreign key of Region(region_id)

Region table has column 'region_name'

These are my models

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :company
    belongs_to :organization    
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :organization
    has_many :employee
end

class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :region
    has_many :company
    has_many :employees, through: :companies
end

class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :companies
    has_many :employees, through: :companies
end
```

How can I search traversing 3 tables and
display the list of employees in index page of Employees of that region?

Note: database-Postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

`Employee.joins(company: {organization: :region}).where(regions: {region_name: 'Your Region Name'})`